# HttpServletRequest can not get xhr request parameter

Tags: javascript, spring, model-view-controller, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am working with Spring and javascript. Calling `@Controller` with `XhrHttpRequest` Object.

I can see my parameter(JSON string) with Chrome Inspector, but when I call `request.getParamter("id")` returns null.

```
Calling part with js
function ajax(url, data, callback, method){
    //data is {"id":"system", "password" : "1234"}
    var httpRequest;
    var afterAction = function(){
        if(!httpRequest) {
            console.error('can not find httpRequest variable');
            return;
        }

        if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                var responseData = httpRequest.responseText;
                //alert(JSON.stringify(responseData));
                console.log('Result of API call >>>', responseData);
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback(JSON.parse(responseData));
                }
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }

    //=========== LOGIC ============
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }

    if(!method) method = 'POST';
    data = (!!data) ? JSON.stringify(data) : '';

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = afterAction;
    httpRequest.open(method.toUpperCase(), url, true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    //httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
    //httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    httpRequest.send(data);
}
```

receive part with Spring `@Controller`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"member"}, produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public class MemberController {

    /**
     * @param request
     * @param resp
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
    public @ResponseBody String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Login request");
        String id = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));                 //returns null
        String password = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("password"));     //returns null

        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        result.put("result", "S");
        result.put("message", "login success");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    }
}
```

I do not know why parameter becomes null. Thanks.

Comment: A JSON body isn't a request parameter. So obviously `getParameter` will return `null`. You will need to parse the body instead of the parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum One of my friend suggested to use `Converter`, I will test that and add to this post. Thanks for sharing information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps to accept `Json` in your controller:

**(1) Define UserLogin bean to hold the Json**

```
public class UserLogin  {
    private String id;
    private String password;

    //Add getters and setters
}
```

**(2) Change your controller to accept Json & receive the UserLogin bean**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"member"}, produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public class MemberController {

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody String login(UserLogin userLogin) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Login request");
        String id = userLogin.getId();            
        String password = userLogin.getPassword();

        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        result.put("result", "S");
        result.put("message", "login success");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks work. However is there any other way that does not make extra bean? since I do not determine what data a user should have.(could be change anytime at this moment and database is OK with that - MongoDB). Further more, I want to handling common way which can share with other controllers.

Comment: Login is just a case. I am going to receive API parameters in JSON. For instance, for list `{"page" : "1", "pageCount" : "10", "search" : "aaa"}`. In way you suggested I have to make another paging bean for it, right? Thanks though, what you have suggested was also wonderful solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is an Alternative way with Jackson Library. I like @javaguy 's way, but using Jackson library could be more flexible so add this post.

Preparations

- `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` implements class or something equivalent with that
- SpringFramework Environment. In my case, `Eclipse Dynamic Web Project` with `Maven` and `spring-webmvc` in `pom.xml`.

What I did...

- Implement `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`
- Override Method `configureMessageConverters`
- Change Controller parameters from `HttpServeletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp` to `@RequestBody Map<?, ?>`.(You can change generic value. It does not matters for further process)

So Here's code.

ServerConfig.java (I block other Options to focus current issue)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={ ... }
, excludeFilters=@ComponentScan.Filter(Configuration.class))
//Filter 걸 때 Configuration.class 를 수동으로 등록해줘야 되는데 나은 방법 찾아보기 
public class ServerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

};
```

And Controller (Change Parameter Types)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"member"}, produces={"application/json"})
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public class MemberApiController {

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value={"/login"})
    public @ResponseBody String login(@RequestBody Map<?, ?> jsonBody) throws JsonProcessingException {
        System.out.println("Login request" + jsonBody.toString());
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String rs = "S";
        String message = "SUCCESS";

        System.out.println("ID >>> ", String.valueOf(jsonBody.get("id")));
        System.out.println("PW >>> ", String.valueOf(jsonBody.get("password")));

        result.put("result", rs);
        result.put("result_msg", message);
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
    }
};
```

However, since as far as I know `@RequestBody` does not have `HttpSession`, If you try to store data to `HttpSession`, you need another parameter `HttpServletRequest`.

I hope this could be a hand to others who has same problem with me  :D

Comment: Anyway, It seems impossible to get JSON value from `HttpServletRequest` itself.